# Github push hook looks different from what's documented

Tags: github, hook, push, githooks

I have a Github repos with a push hook configured.

The payload version is application/vnd.github.v3+form.

The payload object sent with that hook has the keys "before" and "after" and does not have the key "size". This differs from the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent) I can find, which does not document the "before" and "after" keys and indicates that the payload should have a "size" key.

Also, the hook I received has a "repository" object which is not documented at the link above. There may be other differences; I haven't yet compared them systematically.

I'd really like a "size" key, because I'd like to know how many commits were in the push (if there were more than 20, I don't' think the size of the commits object would be helpful).

Also I want to know what "before" and "after" mean, and there may be more differences. Mostly I'm concerned that I'm getting push hook payloads that I can't find the documentation for.

If I wrote my code based on that documentation (for example, expecting a "size" key), it wouldn't work.

Comment: The `before` and `after` keys are probably the ref the branch pointed to before and after the push.  Maybe test it out a little bit using [this](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/configuring/)?